# How do I retrieve wallet name for Monero CLI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, linux

So I have the password, also the magic recovery phrase and this definitely used to work perfectly. Have however forgotten the *name* of my wallet and the CLI is saying:

```
Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
Logging to Downloads/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/monero-wallet-cli.log
Specify wallet file name (e.g., MyWallet). If the wallet doesn't exist, it will be created.
Wallet file name (or Ctrl-C to quit):
```

(In another terminal monerod is running in the background)

Is there a way to find what the name of it was? I know nothing is lost, but it would be less messy to not recreate it.

It does not sound like something which would be as secret or obfuscated as say a password.

Can you give a monero command somewhere to list the wallets on the system, or is it a matter of a linux command to find somewhere in the home directory a file with a certain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On terminal, before starting your cli-wallet, do an `ls` command to see the contents of your currentt directory.

There should be a file with the name of your wallet. Once you see the name of the wallet on that directory, you can go ahead and start your cli-wallet, and then enter the wallet name you have seen before.

Comment: I also suspected that but the trick in my case was a space (" ") before the wallet name when prompted! Not sure if that is a bug in the monero cli or if I originally entered it that way to play a trick on myself..